# Parsing objects from RSS feed in React, why is my code failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, reactjs, rss

I'm trying to parse data from an RSS feed. The error I'm getting at the moment is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined' (see the render() method).

The getNews() method seems to be working correctly and saving the array of item objects to 'news' (see state), as I checked that length of 'news' array was correct (30) in the render method. What am I doing wrong?

```
>class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  news: []
}
this.getNews = this.getNews.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
this.getNews();
}

getNews() {

$.get("https://www.hs.fi/rss/tuoreimmat.xml", function (data) {
  var $xml = $(data);
  var items = [];
  $xml.find("item").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
      item = {
        title: $this.find("title").text(),
        link: $this.find("link").text(),
        description: $this.find("description").text(),
        pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
      }
    items.push(item);
  }.bind(this));
  this.setState({ news: items })
}.bind(this));
}


render() {
var newsItem = this.state.news[1];
var title = newsItem.title

return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <h1 className="App-title">News</h1>
    </header>
    <div className="App-feeds">
    </div>
    <div className="panel-list">{title}</div>
  </div>
);}}
```

Comment: ajax is **asyncnronous** . Same problem as trying to eat a pizza before it gets delivered

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the title before the state has been set. An easy way to fix this is just:

```
var title = newItem && newItem.title
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed the error message, however, it's still not displaying the title?